# Stop video resizing

Tags: html, video, svg, iframe

I've got an embedded video that resizes as soon as it's played in the case of youtube, and as soon as I hover over it in Vimeo. It looks like this before playing:
[image: Before playing]

And like this after playing:
[image: After playing]

And here is the relevant code:

```
            <div id="film-svg">
                    <svg id="_35mm_original" data-name="35mm_original" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 170.73 301.31">
                        <defs>
                            <style>
                            .cls-1 {
                                fill: #fafafa;
                            }

                            .cls-1,
                            .cls-2,
                            .cls-3 {
                                stroke: #282d32;
                                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                            }

                            .cls-2 {
                                fill: #e3e7ea;
                            }

                            .cls-3 {
                                fill: #282d32;
                            }

                            .cls-4 {
                                fill: #fff;
                            }

                            .cls-5,
                            .cls-6 {
                                font-size: 12px;
                                font-family: Roboto;
                                font-weight: 700;
                            }

                            .cls-5,
                            .cls-7 {
                                fill: #586075;
                            }

                            .cls-6 {
                                fill: #afb0b5;
                            }

                            .cls-8 {
                                fill: none;
                                stroke: #fff;
                                stroke-linecap: round;
                                stroke-linejoin: round;
                            }
                            </style>
                        </defs>
                        <title>film_strips</title>
                        <g id="base">
                            <rect class="cls-1" x="18.71" y="0.5" width="133" height="100"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-2" x="18.71" y="100.5" width="133" height="100"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-1" x="18.71" y="200.5" width="133" height="100"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-3" x="0.5" y="0.58" width="17.73" height="300.22"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="6.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="17.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="28.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="39.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="50.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="61.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="72.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="82.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="93.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="104.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="115.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="126.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="137.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="148.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="159.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="169.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="180.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="191.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="202.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="213.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="224.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="235.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="246.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="257.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="267.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="278.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="6.5" y="289.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-3" x="152.5" y="0.58" width="17.73" height="300.22"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="6.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="17.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="28.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="39.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="50.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="61.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="72.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="82.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="93.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="104.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="115.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="126.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="137.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="148.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="159.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="169.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="180.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="191.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="202.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="213.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="224.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="235.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="246.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="257.5" width="6" height="5"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="267.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="278.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <rect class="cls-4" x="158.5" y="289.5" width="6" height="6"></rect>
                            <foreignObject width="133" height="100" x="18.71" y="0.5">
                                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YCoQwZ9BQ9Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </foreignObject>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
</div>
```

The div wrapping the svg seems to need a `width` set so that the video is clickable, so its property is set from CSS to `width: 350px;`.

How do I stop the video from resizing on play or on hover in the case of Vimeo?

Comment: Your `iframe` has a `width` and `height` which are both fixed at `100%`. You could always try changing these values to pixels instead of percentages. Setting it to `100%` will only extend the player out to the maximum size at which it can expand (i.e. 320x240, etc. etc.). You could always try `width="320" height="240"` and see if you get the player to readjust to that size, then make adjustments from there based on the size of your `viewBox`. Let me know if this resolves the issue! (What I mean by 'make adjustments from there' is to play around with larger frame sizes aka larger than 320x240).

Comment: @DrewFarber I thought it could be something related to the iframe size. The problem seems to be that an aspect ratio is being forced upon the video on playback, so even if I guess the correct width the height is thrown off. Not to mention that if the iFrame size is changed than the placeholder image is misaligned, and no longer looks like the 1st pic (the play button moves down and right, partially out of view - on play the video still resizes). On inspection the iFrame is correctly positioned and fills the square as expected - its just the actual video that resizes.

Comment: Have you tried going old school with it and just setting fixed HTML5 video size like so? `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> `. I know it might seem too obvious, but it's always worth a shot.

Comment: @DrewFarber Good idea, but looks like using a url like youtube doesn't do it...

Comment: Grrr... YouTube is such a pain. The only other thing I could think to do would be to set a fixed `width` and `max-width` along with a fixed `height` and `max-height` in your iframe's CSS, along with that of the video itself, and see if that gets anything going. Also, if you do end up finding a solution, post it here because I'm still curious!